What are the strengths and weaknesses of wanting to study everything and how can I use it to my advantage?
I'm a master's student in STEM. I changed my undergraduate major 3 times before settling on physics because it was the most general degree I could find. I'm now in a master's program and need to choose a research topic but I'm having a hard time settling on anything because I'm fascinated by everything. For example, I'm interested in numerical analyis, partial differential equations, nuclear engineering, neuro-imaging, biometrics, theoretical nueroscience, data compression, and more (I've read publications in every field listed). I am finding this to be a real problem for me as I need to choose a research focus to write a thesis on. It's almost like I've developed FOMO about research I haven't done. I am not planning to do a PhD at this time, but I believe I could be a competitive candidate in most of the fields I listed based on my GPA. Am I broken?? What advice can you give me on overcoming this, and how can I use this to my advantage?

I’m interested in all sorts of things, too. Pick something that you believe has good job prospects to focus on, and study the others as a hobby in your free time. Choose a life that gives you plenty of time to keep studying for fun.

As one of the founders of SE said, you have to 'be smart and get things done' - if you can't dive in and get things done then you will not get a PhD no matter how interested you are in all these different things.

I think you're both right. I need to lean into SOMETHING to be able to substainably study more of anything.

‘Am I broken??’ If you’re asking that seriously, see a counselor.

@Significance if you post this as an answer I will accept it. I think that's exactly what I need to do. Thanks again

I initially posted this as a comment, but I’ve been asked to repost it as an answer:
I’m interested in all sorts of things, too. Pick something that you believe has good job prospects to focus on, and study the others as a hobby in your free time. Choose a life that gives you plenty of time to keep studying for fun.

I am also somebody who finds many diverse topics interesting in my subject. There are, as you said, some positives and negatives to this.
Positives:

There will always be something that you want to know more about or work on. This is a huge advantage if you decide to stay in academia.
It's likely that you will always be self-motivated and will take the initiative to learn about the things you are curious about, rather than someone else pushing you to delve deeper into a topic because it is relevant to your field of research.
I've found that knowing (even a little bit) about a lot of different things can help you connect the dots between seemingly unrelated problems/topics. I've found science to be a huge interrelated web of knowledge, so being able to refer to diverse literature and find (or create) solutions from different fields is a huge skill.
Related to my previous point, wanting to learn about multiple things at once may enable you to design a unique research project oriented towards teaching yourself multiple things at once. Your focus doesn't necessarily have to be one thing. You could focus on two or three things if that is something you enjoy and can handle time-/stress-wise.

Negatives:

It's possible that the topics you are interested in may not be the ones that are 'in demand' in industry or 'well-funded' in academia. From this perspective, it's perhaps better to focus on something that will give you transferrable skills or prepare you for a job you want.
It's possible that, even when you're trying to focus on a narrower research idea, you will be pulled in different directions because you find everything interesting. While exploring other topics is fun in and of itself, this might impede your progress in the project you are working on.
Your learning may lack structure. This is something I've faced in my years as a student, research assistant, and PhD candidate. My advisors and I had to work hard to provide me with enough structure for a project that was very exploratory. Much of my learning was driven by reading Stack Overflow or Cross Validated answers, poring over or writing my own code, attending conferences, reading books about the history of my field, and having one-on-one conversations with experts. While this is not necessarily a poor way of learning (in fact, I'd advocate for it), it's not well-suited for everyone. If you're someone who thrives on structure, then you may have to take responsibility (or seek advisors who will) to structure your learning in a way that is not overwhelming.

In general, I think it is a wonderful advantage to want to learn. You sound like you're highly motivated. During your master's, I think it's important to teach yourself the skills required to do good research, write articles, and present your work so that you can apply these to your work. I can understand the FOMO about research you haven't done, but you have a whole lifetime for that!

I think I've met people like you in Philosophy of Science/Science and Technology Studies departments. If you have interest for philosophy, that'd be a subject where you could make good use of your interdisciplinary interests. (For sure it's not the only one, but I thought I mention this one in particular.)

I have a professor who comes from your dept in Bologna! For me, philosophy is not so satisfying since it doesn't produce beautiful plots!

@try_hard There are people working on the role of diagrams and visualisation in science though. (But of course if philosophy is not your cup of tea, so be it.)

My comment may only be applicable for research.
May I mention disadvantage first. One biggest disadvantage is that higher education tend to require deep knowledge in one field, but it is unlikely for person like you, that have wide knowledge, may have a deep knowledge on a subject. Of course if you are genius you may have deep knowledge on many subjects, but unlikely.
The advantage is that nowadays interdisciplinary research is popular, so if you have wide knowledge, that would be helpful.
My suggestion: choose one that you like most to have a deep knowledge on it, while maintaining you wide interest if possible.
